# any idea how this route can be render a specific component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route that looks like this:

```
www.url.com/path/stb?state=mystate&bite=implement&local=true...
```

and I have tried to define this route like this one:

```
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" render={() => <App />} />
            <Route exact path="/path/stb" render={() => <Home />} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

but it doesnt distinguish this path when I go it and it doesnt render any component and 
I know that I misunderstand how to do it properly.

So any assist with that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reorder your routes within Switch

```
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/path/stb" render={() => <Home />} />
        <Route path="/" render={() => <App />} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

The reason for the Above change is that Switch renders the first matching Component and when you are on `/path/stb` the path with `/` also matches as it is a prefix routes. So the idea with the above change is that prefix routes are written at the end

Comment: Are you using browserRouter? Also are you trying to just change the link from url? If so have you configured your build server to return index.html for every path that you try to visit

Answer (score 0):

```
<Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={<App />} />
            <Route exact path="/path/stb" component={<Home />} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Try this way. And Just import those files.(App and Homes)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `exact` attribute from other route and it to default route.

```
<Router>
     <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <App />} />
        <Route path="/path/stb" render={() => <Home />} />
     </Switch>
</Router>
```